# steps I need to take to make my flask webpage visible by others

Tags: python, flask, deployment, web-deployment

I have a webpage with some simple algorithm, which returns the output based on user input & local data file. I checked it's working with my local machine, but found that it doesn't work from my cell phone / other laptops.

I tried several things from web - such as 'python app.py --host=0.0.0.0' on my terminal, or app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000) but didn't work.

I'm trying again from the beginning. below is my code (I named the file app.py), where I put it back to default before any edit.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for,request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])`
def predict():
#some algorithm stuffs
    return render_template('result.html',  tables=[result.to_html(classes='data',escape=False)], titles=result.columns.values)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

what should I add on this py file?
Also, is there anything beside coding I should do? (firewall, port, etc) I'm currently starting with local machine and planning to work it with virtual machine later (EC2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it visible by anyone you have to open at least one port of your box (depending on your box model you can find some explanations on how to do it), this can be unsafe. You'll then have to map your box port with your PC's port.

You should go straight with a cloud virtual machine as it's much easier (just allow connexion to the VM port 80)

A good alternative would be to use Docker and deploy your app on Heroku or Azure (it's free!)

If you want to make it visible on your own network (just the people on the same WIFI) then it's easier but I don't think that's your point

Comment: Hi Vincent, thank you for sharing solutions. If possible, do you mind sharing me some reference to setup a connection for a virtual machine? I think this method fits most with my circumstance.

Comment: You're welcome :)I've only done it with a linux Azure VM. You do the same as you do in local and deploy on port 80 with app.run(port=80), it will save you a lot of time as this port is somehow predefined for that. If you google smth like 'deploy flask server azure vm' you'll definitely find a tuto

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy your application in your own local network and make it accessible to your phone or to other computers in the network for testing reasons, then the following steps is enough:

- Make sure your computer is connected to your access point and receives an ip address, then launch your application with the command: `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` which tells your operating system to listen on all public IPs.
- Check the ip address of your machine and the port number on which flask is running (eg: `192.168.43.114:5000`). Type it in the browser on your phone or another computer on the network and you will have access to your application.

If you want a larger deployment, for example having computers in other networks access your application, then you need to consider other strategies. Here are a few examples, all of which relate to a specific use case:

- [Flask-ngrok](https://github.com/gstaff/flask-ngrok)
- [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/)
- [Excellent tutorial about deployement on heroku](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xviii-deployment-on-heroku)